# Capture data spliced from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function which splices data from an array.

```
    function findAndRemove(array, property, value) {
        array.forEach(function(result, index) {
        if(result[property] === value) {
        //Remove from array
        array.splice(index, 1);
        }    
    });
    }
```

With the same function how can I capture the data being spliced from the array.

Lets say `var ar = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];`
If I'm splicing `1,2` I will have an araay with `var ar = [3, 4, 5];`

From this I want another array to be with this output
`var ar1 = [1, 2];`

**Edit:**

What changes will i need to make to the solution suggested by @Shivaji Varma such that the spliced data is not removed from the array `list` but is just copied to `var removedItems = []`.

I tried pushing it back to the array but there's no change is the dataset.

I have also tried merging the two arrays but even that failed to work.

Comment: Well then push the value you just removed inside the loop into a new array …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone the existing array to a `newarray` like in the below-edited code. With this, the initial array `list` remains unchanged when the function is called.

```
var list = [
  { id : 10,Name : 'abc' },
  { id : 20,Name : 'xyz' },
 { id : 30,Name : 'mno' }
];

var removedItems = [];

function findAndRemove(array, property, value){
 var newarray = [...array]
 var index = newarray.map(function(x){ return x[property]; }).indexOf(value);
 var removedItem = newarray.splice(index,1);
 removedItems.push(removedItem);
}

findAndRemove(list, 'id', 20);
console.log(list);
console.log(removedItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

As a fan of functional programming and immutability, I would do it this way:

```js
function findAndRemove(array, property, value) {
  const removed = array.filter(item => item[property] === value);
  const kept = array.filter(item => item[property] !== value);
  return {"kept": kept, "removed": removed};
}

const arr = [{id: 1},{id: 2},{id: 3},{id: 4},{id: 5}]
console.log(findAndRemove(arr, 'id', 3).removed);
```

It it also possible to put it into a single `.reduce` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var list = [
  { id : 10,Name : 'abc' },
  { id : 20,Name : 'xyz' },
  { id : 30,Name : 'mno' }
];

var removedItems = [];

function findAndRemove(array, property, value){
  var index = array.map(function(x){ return x[property]; }).indexOf(value);
  var removedItem = array.splice(index,1);
  removedItems.push(removedItem);
}

findAndRemove(list, 'id', 20);
console.log(list);
console.log(removedItems);
```